# Downcase the first letter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, textbox

I am new to react-native. How do I downcase the first letter of a TextBox? I saw on https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput to use enum('words') but don't know how to apply it.

Could you please help me?

*EDITED*

```
render() {
function capitalizeFirstLetter(string) {
    return string.charAt(0).toDownerCase()+ string.slice(1);
}
var newString = downcaseFirstLetter(value);
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <TextInput style={styles.inputBox}/>
            onChangeText={(email) => this.setState({email})}
            underlineColorAndroid='rgba(0,0,0,0)' 
            placeholder="Email"
            placeholderTextColor = "#232122"
            selectionColor="#232122"
            keyboardType="email-address"
            onSubmitEditing={()=> this.password.focus()}
    />
```

Perdon, I am new to JavaScript, but is it like this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make the first letter of a string uppercase in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026069/how-do-i-make-the-first-letter-of-a-string-uppercase-in-javascript)

Comment: Does this work on React-Native too? Ill give it a try

Comment: Yeah, it's just javascript

Answer (score 0):

To use `autoCapitalize`, the enum is an attribute/property of the TextBox, so it would be  `autoCapitalize="words"`

```
<TextInput autoCapitalize="words" />
```

or as another example, capitalizing the first letter of each sentence (which is the default)

```
<TextInput autoCapitalize="sentences" />
```

Although this would capitalize, not downcase. You need javascript to do that as @Travis James said

```
function downcaseFirstLetter(string) {
    return string.charAt(0).toLowerCase() + string.slice(1);
}

var newString = downcaseFirstLetter(value);
```

Comment: Sir do I code it like this?                                                                            
                <TextInput style={styles.inputBox}  autoCapitalize="words"/>

Comment: Yes, that would autoCapitalize "first letter of each word." as the documentation says, but it sounds like you want to downcase the first letter, which would require javascript